# Find whether given sum exists over a path in a BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The question is to find whether a given sum exists over any path in a BST. The question is damn easy if a path means root to leaf, or easy if the path means a portion of a path from root to leaf that may not include the root or the leaf. But it becomes difficult here, because a path may span both left and right child of a node. For example, in the given figure, a sum of 132 exists over the circled path. How can I find the existence of such a path? Using hash to store all possible sums under a node is frowned upon!

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? I'd look at all-pairs shortest path algorithms for inspiration. (moved to comment after deleting my suggestion)

Comment: Is there a limit on how large the sum can be? Would a solution with a big-oh involving an upper limit for the sum be good enough? What complexity do you hope to achieve?

Comment: My suggestion is to compute the all-pairs path costs, which is v^3 for arbitrary graphs and can possibly be optimized given that you're working with a tree (v^3 = n^3 in this case).  Does that violate your "hashes are frowned on" constraint?

Comment: Kind of. Storing sums is a non-no, be it in a hash or an array. A normal recursive solution like the one employed to find whether such a path exists from root to leaf is preferred.

Comment: @IVlad, The sum would be well within limit, so that won't pose a problem. I dunno about the complexity, the best would do!

Comment: A simple algorithm that runs is O(n²) is to search from each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly generate all possible paths, summing incrementally as you go.  The fact that the tree is a BST might let you save time by bounding out certain sums, though I'm not sure that will give an asymptotic speed increase.  The problem is that a sum formed using the left child of a given node will not necessarily be less than a sum formed using the right child, since the path for the former sum could contain many more nodes.  The following algorithm will work for all trees, not just BSTs.

To generate all possible paths, notice that the topmost point of a path is special: it's the only point in a path which is allowed (though not required) to have both children contained in the path.  Every path contains a unique topmost point.  Therefore the outer layer of recursion should be to visit every tree node, and to generate all paths that have that node as the topmost point.

```
// Report whether any path whose topmost node is t sums to target.
// Recurses to examine every node under t.
EnumerateTopmost(Tree t, int target) {
    // Get a list of sums for paths containing the left child.
    // Include a 0 at the start to account for a "zero-length path" that
    // does not contain any children.  This will be in increasing order.
    a = append(0, EnumerateSums(t.left))
    // Do the same for paths containing the right child.  This needs to
    // be sorted in decreasing order.
    b = reverse(append(0, EnumerateSums(t.right)))

    // "List match" to detect any pair of sums that works.
    // This is a linear-time algorithm that takes two sorted lists --
    // one increasing, the other decreasing -- and detects whether there is
    // any pair of elements (one from the first list, the other from the
    // second) that sum to a given value.  Starting at the beginning of
    // each list, we compute the current sum, and proceed to strike out any
    // elements that we know cannot be part of a satisfying pair.
    // If the sum of a[i] and b[j] is too small, then we know that a[i]
    // cannot be part of any satisfying pair, since all remaining elements
    // from b that it could be added to are at least as small as b[j], so we
    // can strike it out (which we do by advancing i by 1).  Similarly if
    // the sum of a[i] and b[j] is too big, then we know that b[j] cannot
    // be part of any satisfying pair, since all remaining elements from a
    // that b[j] could be added to are at least as big as a[i], so we can
    // strike it out (which we do by advancing j by 1).  If we get to the
    // end of either list without finding the right sum, there can be
    // no satisfying pair.
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while (i < length(a) and j < length(b)) {
        if (a[i] + b[j] + t.value < target) {
            i = i + 1
        } else if (a[i] + b[j] + t.value > target) {
            j = j + 1
        } else {
            print "Found!  Topmost node=", t
            return
        }
    }

    // Recurse to examine the rest of the tree.
    EnumerateTopmost(t.left)
    EnumerateTopmost(t.right)
}

// Return a list of all sums that contain t and at most one of its children,
// in increasing order.
EnumerateSums(Tree t) {
    If (t == NULL) {
        // We have been called with the "child" of a leaf node.
        return []     // Empty list
    } else {
        // Include a 0 in one of the child sum lists to stand for
        // "just node t" (arbitrarily picking left here).
        // Note that even if t is a leaf node, we still call ourselves on
        // its "children" here -- in C/C++, a special "NULL" value represents
        // these nonexistent children.
        a = append(0, EnumerateSums(t.left))
        b = EnumerateSums(t.right)
        Add t.value to each element in a
        Add t.value to each element in b
        // "Ordinary" list merge that simply combines two sorted lists
        // to produce a new sorted list, in linear time.
        c = ListMerge(a, b)
        return c
    }
}
```

The above pseudocode only reports the topmost node in the path.  The entire path can be reconstructed by having `EnumerateSums()` return a list of pairs `(sum, goesLeft)` instead of a plain list of sums, where `goesLeft` is a boolean that indicates whether the path used to generate that sum initially goes left from the parent node.

The above pseudocode calculates sum lists multiple times for each node: `EnumerateSums(t)` will be called once for each node above `t` in the tree, in addition to being called for `t` itself.  It would be possible to make `EnumerateSums()` memoise the list of sums for each node so that it's not recomputed on subsequent calls, <s>but actually this doesn't improve the asymptotics: only O(n) work is required to produce a list of n sums using the plain recursion, and changing this to O(1) doesn't change the overall time complexity because the entire list of sums produced by any call to `EnumerateSums()` must in general be read by the caller anyway, and this requires O(n) time.</s> **EDIT:** As pointed out by Evgeny Kluev, `EnumerateSums()` actually behaves like a merge sort, being O(nlog n) when the tree is perfectly balanced and O(n^2) when it is a single path.  So memoisation will in fact give an asymptotic performance improvement.

It is possible to get rid of the temporary lists of sums by rearranging `EnumerateSums()` into an iterator-like object that performs the list merge lazily, and can be queried to retrieve the next sum in increasing order.  This would entail also creating an `EnumerateSumsDown()` that does the same thing but retrieves sums in decreasing order, and using this in place of `reverse(append(0, EnumerateSums(t.right)))`.  Doing this brings the space complexity of the algorithm down to O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the tree, since each iterator object requires constant space (pointers to left and right child iterator objects, plus a place to record the last sum) and there can be at most one per tree node.

Comment: I am having a little problem with understanding your code, mainly due to the language you are using. Can you please add a few more comments?

Comment: I've fleshed out the comments a bit, hope that helps.  If you have any specific questions, please just ask :)

Comment: I am a bit confused, the `listmerge` you described in your comment doesn't match with the way you have used it in `EnumerateSums`. According to your description, it is supposed to return a boolean, but here it is returning a list.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: that's right, it is confusing. I'd rather call the procedure, used in "EnumerateTopmost", *list match* instead of *list merge*. And leave the name *list merge* for the procedure in "EnumerateSums".

Comment: I cannot agree with this conclusion: "only O(n) work is required to produce a list of n sums using the plain recursion". In fact, it is similar to merge sort, which is O(N log N), and for imbalanced tree this may be O(N^2). So memorizing the list of sums for each node should improve performance. But instead, I'd use bottom-up approach. Compute sums for chains, containing leaf nodes, trim the chain if its sum exceeds target value. Match chains, that are descendants of one node, then merge them together. Continue until the tree is merged into a single chain.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: "List merge" is confusing, I'll change it.  (I was looking for some term that describes what this matching algorithm and the list merge have in common...)  You're right about O(nlog n) time, don't know how I messed that up.  I don't follow your bottom-up approach though.  What do you mean by "chain"?

Comment: By "chain" I mean part of the tree without branches (when nodes have exactly one descendant). At the same time lists of sums I also call "chains".

Comment: To clean up the confusion with "chains": Compute sums for chains, containing leaf nodes, trim the chain if its sum exceeds target value. Match lists of sums for sub-trees, that are descendants of one node, then merge them together. Continue until the tree is merged into a single list of sums.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: When you say "trim the chain if its sum exceeds target value": I'm confused because it sounds like you're saying we should only consider chains in which nodes at the leaf end have been trimmed off when the chain sum exceeds the target, but we also need to consider chains that are even shorter than this.

Comment: If we have target sum = 5, some chain {2, 2, 2, 2}, and list of sums for this chain {2, 4, 6, 8}, we first try to find a sub-chain/sub-list, that matches this target. This search fails. Then we may drop all sums greater than 5, which gives a shorter list {2, 4}. Just an optimization.

Comment: I'm assuming only positive values in the tree. If that's not true, it's not good to trim the lists.

Comment: I think, the bottom-up approach is still not easy to follow reading these comments, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

i would in order traverse the left subtree and in reverse order traverse the right subtree at the same time kind of how merge sort works. each time move the iterator that makes the aum closer.like merge sort almost. its order n

Comment: Can you please give a example of sudo code for this approach ?

Comment: no sorry. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote this. But perhaps imagine A worm with two heads. Start with two heads at the bottom left. Now one head goes off eating numbers growing the worm until it's bigger than the sum. Then you have to spit out a number from one of the two heads. You want to do this in a way that allows for "branch and bound". So if you spit out the lowest left node, you never want to go back there again. Each head can traverse the whole tree i guess, but it's not N^2 because you're trying to fit the worm around the tree so the heads are the right distance apart.

Answer (score 2):

Not the fastest, but simple approach would be to use two nested depth-first searches.

Use normal depth-first search to get starting node. Use second, modified version of depth-first search to check sums for all paths, starting from this node.

[image]

Second depth-first search is different from normal depth-first search in two details:

1. It keeps current path sum. It adds value to the sum each time a new node is added to the path and removes value from the sum when some node is removed.
2. It traverses edges of the path from root to the starting node only in opposite direction (red edges on diagram). All other edges are traversed in proper direction, as usual (black edges on diagram). To traverse edges in opposite direction, it either uses "parent" pointers of the original BST (if there are any), or peeks into the stack of first depth-first search to obtain these "parent" pointers.

Time complexity of each DFS in O(N), so total time complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup>). Space requirements are O(N) (space for both DFS stacks). If original BST contains "parent" pointers, space requirements are O(1) ("parent" pointers allow traversing the tree in any direction without stacks).

---

Other approach is based on ideas by j_random_hacker and robert king (maintaining lists of sums, matching them, then merging them together). It processes the tree in bottom-up manner (starting from leafs).

Use DFS to find some leaf node. Then go back and find the last branch node, that is a grand-...-grand-parent of this leaf node. This gives a chain between branch and leaf nodes. Process this chain:

```
match1(chain)
sum_list = sum(chain)

match1(chain):
  i = j = sum = 0
  loop:
    while (sum += chain[i]) < target:
      ++i
    while (sum -= chain[j]) > target:
      ++j
    if sum == target:
      success!

sum(chain):
  result = [0]
  sum = 0
  i = chain.length - 1
  loop:
    sum += chain[i]
    --i
    result.append(sum)
  return result
```

[image]

Continue DFS and search other leaf chains. When two chains, coming from the same node are found, possibly preceded by another chain (red and green chains on diagram, preceded by blue chain), process these chains:

```
match2(parent, sum_list1, sum_list2)
sum_list3 = merge1(parent, sum_list1, sum_list2)

if !chain3.empty:
  match1(chain3)
  match3(sum_list3, chain3)
  sum_list4 = merge2(sum_list3, chain3)

match2(parent, sum_list1, sum_list2):
  i = 0
  j = chain2.length - 1
  sum = target - parent.value
  loop:
    while sum < sum_list1[i] + sum_list2[j]:
      ++i
    while sum > sum_list1[i] + sum_list2[j]:
      --j
    if sum == sum_list1[i] + sum_list2[j]:
      success!

merge1(parent, sum_list1, sum_list2):
  result = [0, parent.value]
  i = j = 1
  loop:
    if sum_list1[i] < sum_list2[j]:
      result.append(parent.value + sum_list1[i])
      ++i
    else:
      result.append(parent.value + sum_list2[j])
      ++j
  return result

match3(sum_list3, chain3):
  i = sum = 0
  j = sum_list3.length - 1
  loop:
    sum += chain3[i++]
    while sum_list3[j] + sum > target:
      --j
    if sum_list3[j] + sum == target:
      success!

merge2(sum_list3, chain3):
  result = [0]
  sum = 0
  i = chain3.length - 1
  loop:
    sum += chain3[i--]
    result.append(sum)
  result.append(sum_list3[1...] + sum)
```

Do the same wherever any two lists of sums or a chain and a list of sums are descendants of the same node. This process may be continued until a single list of sums, belonging to root node, remains.

Comment: Ah! I see now.  When you say "It traverses edges of the path from root to the starting node only in opposite direction", you mean it performs a DFS on the tree that consists of all the directed edges of the original tree, except that the edges between the root and the starting node have been reversed.  Clever!

Comment: This examines every path twice, once starting from each end. To avoid most of this, you can pass a 2nd parameter recording the height above the starting node to each recursive call in the 2nd DFS, and force recursion to stop when this drops below 0.  (Paths between nodes of equal height will still be calculated twice though.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining your bottom-up algorithm, it took me a while but I think I understand it now :) One thing: I think `match3()` also needs to check for paths having the target sum that are entirely contained within the preceding (blue) chain, the same way `match1()` does.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any complexity restrictions?
As you stated: "*easy if a path means root to leaf, or easy if the path means a portion of a path from root to leaf that may not include the root or the leaf*".
You can reduce the problem to this statement by setting the root each time to a different node and doing the search n times.
That would be a straightforward approach, not sure if optimal.

**Edit**: if the tree is unidirectional, something of this kind might work (pseudocode):

```
findSum(tree, sum)
    if(isLeaf(tree))
        return (sum == tree->data)
    for (i = 0 to sum)
        isfound |= findSum(leftSubStree, i) && findSum(rightSubTree, sum-i)
    return isfound;
```

Probably lots of mistakes here, but hopefully it clarifies the idea.

Comment: How can that yield a solution? Those two cases always traverse in one direction only, down. Here the path may span two subtrees of a node, in which case, to go from one end of the path to another, you may have to traverse up for some time, then down.

Comment: @Cupidvogel Your image doesn't specify direction so I assumed you can move at any direction. If it's a theoretical question, normally it's valid, unless stated otherwise. Anyway, I've added another suggestion for a unidirectional tree.

Comment: I think this solution mostly works if the root of the tree is part of the solution, but the `sum` should be decreased by `tree->data` at each step.
To fix that, I think there needs to be an initial findSum(tree, sum) call per (promising) node in the BST. So, we'd look only at nodes for which the total sum in their subtree is greater or equal to sum (thereby removing the lower levels presumably).
If there is a solution, we'd find it when calling findSum from the lowest common ancestors of the deepest nodes in the solution.
In any case, you could prune some nodes based on the subtree sum.

Comment: @DanFilimon Thanks Dan, you're probably right. My code was just a sketch of a general idea.

Comment: @icepack, sure, you came up with it! :P
I now want to hear from Cupidvogel if it's an acceptable answer.